# Center align text in a rotated triangle

Tags: css

I've created a CSS triangle which contains a rotated text. The text will change depending on different markets and languages, and therefore will be of various lengths. I need it to always be centered and I can't get it to work, especially when the text falls into two rows.

I've tried rotating the parent element instead of the text element and I've been testing around with the transform-origin property and with margins but still no luck.

Any suggestions? [I've created a fiddle here.](http://jsfiddle.net/3NuF6/3/)

Thanks!

My HTML:

```
<div class="container">                      
    <div class="badge">                      
        <div class="badge-text">
            Test 
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

My CSS:

```
 .container {
    position: relative;
}

.badge {
    width: 0px;
    height: 0px;
    border-style: solid;
    border-width: 0 100px 100px 0;
    border-color: transparent #2864cb transparent transparent;
    position: absolute;
    right: 0;
    top: 0;
    color: white;
}

.badge-text {
    position: absolute;
    margin: 25px;
    text-align: center;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    width: 85px;
    transform: rotate(45deg);
    -ms-transform: rotate(45deg);
    -webkit-transform: rotate(45deg);
}
```

Comment: The test seems to look fine to me, what's wrong with it? it seems to be centered OK

Comment: The problem is that it will not contain one word. If you add one or two more words to "Test" it will align badly.

Comment: I don't think this is achievable since your parent div has 0 width and height and your text is interchangable

Answer (score 0):

As the text can be of variable length, I'd suggest you add the following 2 css rules,

```
.badge-text {
..

    overflow: hidden;
    text-overflow: ellipsis;

..
}
```

and add the complete text in the `title` attribute of the element.

This will ensure that you have the worst cases covered, as IMO you're never going to be able to always center align text with variable length.

[JS Fiddle:](http://jsfiddle.net/3NuF6/17/)

[MDN: text-overflow](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/text-overflow?redirectlocale=en-US&redirectslug=CSS/text-overflow)

Answer (score -1):

i think the best solution would be to place it as far at the bottom as possible(so it fits large words) and then make it extend from one edge to the other so the text is always centered, despite the size of the word. try this(you can remove the border);
http://jsfiddle.net/3NuF6/18/

```
.badge-text {
   border: 1px solid;
left: -15px;
margin: 25px;
position: absolute;
text-align: center;
text-transform: uppercase;
top: 9px;
transform: rotate(45deg);
width: 95px;
```

}

update: if you want 2 words the space is significantly smaller so try something like this or i woudl suggest bigger triangle http://jsfiddle.net/3NuF6/20/

```
.badge-text {
border: 1px solid;
left: 3px;
margin: 25px;
position: absolute;
text-align: center;
text-transform: uppercase;
top: -5px;
transform: rotate(45deg);
width: 75px;
```

}